# Liquid markup to detect current page URL?

Tags: html, url, github, jekyll, liquid

I've just recently started using Github to host my blog (using Jekyll and Liquid). However, I'm having [an issue which I can't currently fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831480/github-pages-adding-random-tags-to-my-posts). The issue could be hacked/solved if I was able to detect which "page" or "url" the user was visiting.

Something like:

```
{% if user_is_currently_at_this_url %}
    {{ display something }}
{% else %}
    {{ display something else }}
{% endif %}
```

Is this possible? Is there any other way around this issue?

Comment: `page.url` or `{{ page.url  | absolute_url }}` in case you want to get absolute URL

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`page.url` is the URL of the current page, without the host (e.g. `/index.html`), as documented in [Page Variables](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/#page-variables). So, in this case:

```
{% if page.url == "/index.html" %}
   something
{% else %}
   other thing
{% endif %}
```

(However, I don't think you need this any more, your other problem is probably solved. :) )

Comment: Yes to my problem being already solved, but thank you for this :)

Comment: `page.path` might be better as illustrated at https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-help/issues/5#issuecomment-39033862

Comment: This doesn't work for 404 redirects on github pages :(

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr did you happen to find any solution for that?

Comment: Sadly, no I did not :(

Comment: This might not always return the browser's current URL. In the case of a 404, for example, the user's browser could be pointed to one URL (site.com/page/that/does/not/exist) but the rendered page's URL or path could be different (404.html, say)

Answer (score 4):

You could use `{{ canonical_url }}`